# Devise/Rails: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm a bit confused about how devise is routing my requests, for some reason I can't go to the sign-out path in my app now:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out")
```

Here is what my routes related to my User model and Devise look like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
devise_scope :user do
  get '/settings' => 'registrations#edit'
end
```

Would defining that scope prevent my other routes from working as well?

**Update**

I don't think that it's supposed to be `GET` request, as my link looks like:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: It should be a DELETE request. What would happen if you just leave   devise_for :users in your routes?

Comment: Is your javascript throwing any errors? It's actually the unobtrusive javascript that is going to make this be a DELETE http call.

Comment: What does your Devise config file have for the following item: ```config.sign_out_via```

Comment: @jesse you're correct, I needed to include `jquery-ujs` for it to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keep your `devise.rb` using the correct HTTP method:

```rb
# good 
config.sign_out_via = :delete

# bad
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Use `button_to` instead of `link_to`

```rb
# good 
= button_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete

# bad
= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete"
```

If you are using bootstrap (keep it classy)

```rb
= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm"
```

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4570#issuecomment-740812109

Comment: This is in retrospect the correct answer. Especially when it comes to security and http best practices.

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20):

If you try to go to /users/sign_out by typing it in the address bar of your browser, or linking to it normally, you will get this error. To summarize some comments and answers here and from issues at the devise repo on github:

This is the intended functionality, RESTful apps should not modify state with a GET request.

You can fix this by making a link that uses the DELETE method as mentioned by @Trip, @fuzzyalej, and the update by @Joseph Silvashy.

Alternatively, (and less recommended), in /config/initializers/devise.rb, you could make the following change

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

I came across this issue while following along with http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise and with the older version of devise he's using there, this was not an issue.

Comment: For me, `application.js` was just plain missing (rails 4 template from railswizard.com) and needed the lines:  
`//= jquery
//= jquery_ujs`

Answer (score 8):

Just so this post has an answer :

This must be sent with the method, `delete` so that it does not default to a `get`

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

in your **routes.rb**.

Answer (score 7):

in Rails 7 the `destroy_user_session_path` changes a bit on the method.

instead of using the traditional `method: :delete` that came with the jquery and rails_ujs. Now you need to change that to    `..., data: {turbo_method: :delete}` and you don't need to setup any additional rails_ujs or jquery

Comment: It's still not working.  It's still trying to use a 'get' instead of a 'delete' method.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SSL with Devise controllers, and trying to sign out from an 'http' url, what's happening is it's sending the DELETE request to the #destroy method, but then redirecting to the https version via GET.  You can fix this by adding the https to the sign out link like so:

```
= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_url(protocol: 'https'), method: :delete
```

Note: must be 'url' instead of 'path'

Comment: after change: Secure Connection Failed!  (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Answer (score 0):

From the [rails documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/):

```
link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
# => <a href='http://www.example.com' rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Destroy</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to solve it took these steps:
1) include the //= require jquery_ujs in the assets/javascripts/application.js
2) add gem 'jquery-rails' to my gemfile
3) bundle install

... and it worked.